# How to delay animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a link. When I hover over it, there should be a delay of 1-2 seconds, after which a `div` will appear. The `div` should stay when I hover over it.

If I am not hovering on either the link or the `div`, the `div` should disappear after a delay of 1-2 seconds.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Could someone help? What I'm trying to achieve is similar to how Google sows previews of websites.

```
var formHide;
$('.toggleDisForm').hover(function() {
   var form = $(this).parents("li").find(".dispenserForm");
   function showIt() {
      form.fadeIn();
   }
   show = setTimeout(showIt, 1000);
   clearTimeout(formHide);
}, function() {
   var form = $(this).parents("li").find(".dispenserForm");
   function hideIt() {
      form.fadeOut();
   }
   clearTimeout(show);
   hideDispen = setTimeout(hideIt, 1000);
   $('.dispenserForm').not(form).hide();
});

var hideDispen;
$('.dispenserForm').hover(function() {
   $('.dispenserForm').not(this).hide();
   clearTimeout(hideDispen);
}, function() {
   var form = $(this);
   function showMe() {
      form.show();
   }
   formHide = setTimeout(showMe, 1000);
});
```

Her is the markup

```
<ul class="clearfix">       
    <li>
        <div class="inner">
            <a class="toggleDisForm" href="#">hover
                       <div class="dispenserForm">
                The div that should appear
                  </div>
                    </a>
        </div>

    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="inner">
            <a class="toggleDisForm" href="#">hover
                       <div class="dispenserForm">
                The div that should appear
                  </div>
                    </a>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="inner">
            <a class="toggleDisForm" href="#">hover
                       <div class="dispenserForm">
                The div that should appear
                  </div>
                    </a>
        </div>
    </li>

    etc...      
</ul>
```

Comment: And your HTML mark-up would be..? What have you tried? Have you looked at the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin? Anything else?

Comment: What is your question? How to delay animations? How to do animations? How to create hover effects... Your question needs to be more specific; not just how do I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted isn't working because code inside setTimeout is run in the global scope. `this` no longer refers to the same thing anymore. Try something like this:

```
$('.toggleDisForm').hover(function() {
   var form = $(this).parents("li").find(".dispenserForm");
   function showIt() {
      form.show();
   }
   show = setTimeout(showIt, 2000);
}, function() {
   clearTimeout(show);
   $('.dispenserForm').hide();
});
```

In general, it's better practice to use setTimeout this way (with a function instead of a string).

**EDIT:** In response to your comment, let's see if we can get it to hang around a little bit after it's shown.

```
var formHide;
$('.toggleDisForm').hover(function() {
   var form = $(this).parents("li").find(".dispenserForm");
   function showIt() {
      form.show();
   }
   show = setTimeout(showIt, 2000);
   clearTimeout(formHide);
}, function() {
   var form = $(this).parents("li").find(".dispenserForm");
   function hideIt() {
      form.hide();
   }
   clearTimeout(show);
   hide = setTimeout(hideIt, 1500);
   $('.dispenserForm').not(form).hide();
});
$('.dispenserForm').hover(function() {
   $('.dispenserForm').not(this).hide();
   clearTimeout(hide);
}, function() {
   var form = $(this);
   function hideMe() {
      form.hide();
   }
   formHide = setTimeout(hideMe, 500);
});
```

Does that work?

Comment: this is better, but when I move my mouse away from the link and onto the .dispenserForm div, it disappears.

Comment: Hmm, would it be possible to change your markup so the dispenserForm div is inside the toggleDisForm element? I think all of the answers here would run into that problem.

Comment: yes, that is possible. I tried changing the markup, and it seems that only one thing is missing now. If I mouse out, the div disappears right away. I need it to stay for 1-2 sec and disappear unless I quickly mouse in again. Thanks for the help so far..

Comment: OK, I added some extra code that should do what you described. There are a couple of lines in there that are basically just making sure that there's only one dispenserForm visible at a time, and I had it hide immediately after taking the mouse off of the dispenserForm.

Comment: Almost, I removed the last part.

, function() { $(this).hide(); }

If I mouseout from link and back again the div disappears and returns. This should not happen. But everything else works perfect. I can now move from link to div and back again to link.

Comment: Alright, so I guess it'd be best to use another timeout with the div as well (maybe half a second). I'll edit that in.

Comment: still the same problem with the link going from mouseout (not onto div), and back to link, makes the div go away and come back. Also going from div to link, makes the div go away, it show stay

Comment: I have updated the code, so now only the problem with going from div to empty air to link, is not working. but maybe this is OK.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Just use [.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) before your animations. Like this

```
$(foo).delay(2000).show(200);
```

and remember to use [.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to avoid building up a queue of animations

Answer (score 2):

Using a timer is the cleanest way since it allows you to clear the timer easily if the user moves away from your link.

```
$('.yourLink').hover(function() {
   show = setTimeout('$("#yourDiv").show();', 2000);
}, function() {
   clearTimeout(show);
   $('#yourDiv').hide();
});
```

This is just my implementation; what you are looking for is a tooltip feature, and there are plenty of really good tooltip plugins out there.  I'd suggest using one of those.

Edit: Jan's implementation works also, with just one small caveat; for .delay() to work, the command just be animated.  This just means that you can't use .show() w/o putting in a delay timer:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
   $("div").delay(2000).show(1);
}, function() {
   $('div').stop(true,true).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried it, but nothing happens.